# WPF Data Binding to property that returns class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a class that encapsulates several other classes that have more detailed definitions. For example

```
class MyProperties
{
    SubProperties Props { get; set; }
}

class SubProperties
{
    double MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to bind to this subproperty, "MyValue"? I'd like to have a label display the value of MyValue by referencing MyProperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just like in a C# code, you access property with dot operator.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Props.MyValue}" />
```

If that doesn't work, check if your data context is set properly and your view models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: Wow that was something special on my part. I tried that but had a typo! Anyways, it is working now, thank you.